# Angular Ui-Grid upload grid externally not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a grid which is updated by a form. A user clicks on a row, form is populated, user edits those values and then, he submits them.

**VehicleController.js**

```
$scope.saveEdition = function (vehicle) {
    $scope.message = null;
    $scope.errors = [];

    if (!vehicle.id) {   // Create
       //...
    } else {    // Update
        VehicleService.update(vehicle)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.message = data.message;
                // Here comes the issue 
                VehicleService.list().then(function (vehicles) {
                    $scope.vehicleGrid.data = vehicles;
                    $scope.vehicleGrid.columnDefs = ProcedureService.getColumns(vehicles[0], 'vehicle');
                });
            }).error(function (data) {
                $scope.errors = data.errors;
            });
    }
};
```

**VehicleService.js**

```
factory.list = function() {
    return $http.get('vehicles/').then(function (results) {
        return results.data;
    });
};
```

Factory method **update** works fine, but when you try to **list** again, updating the datagrid (*$scope.vehicleGrid.data = vehicles*, vehicleGrid is *gridOptions* in Ui-Grid api) nothing happens.

I've tried adding that at the end of *VehicleService.list()...* function:

```
$scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.EDIT);
```

but the grid is not refreshing.

Anyone knows what is happening? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you resolve you issue?

Comment: Yep, if I remember well, problem was in the service. You should work with promises, injecting `$q` to the service and returning, for instance, these responses `def.resolve(success.data);` or `def.reject(error.data)` (if fails)

Comment: I'm not sure that I quite got you, this is my service `var modifyEvent = function (event) {
           return $http({
               method   : 'PUT',
               url      : apiUrl + event.id,
               data     : event
           }, event)
           .then(function success (result) {
               $log.info("Update Successful");
               return result.data;
           }, function error( res ) {
               $log.error(" update has been failed ", res)
           });` where should I pass $q??

Comment: If you're working with controllers and services/factories, these ones should send a _promise_ to the controllers, as they won't wait until `$http` method finishes. It's something like "I'll resolve it later", check out here the 2nd code block: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q